# Subsonic Repository BuildUpdateQuery Bug?

Tags: subsonic

I am using ActiveRecord and when I call Model.Save which calls
repositry.Update and then BuildUpdateQuery, it checks to see if item
is ActiveRecord and then return dirty columns.  I don't have any dirty
columns.  I assume this is because I haven't changed anything on my model but the problem is is that it continues to try and update the database with no columns set so you get UPDATE TABLE WHERE ID = 22

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, I take it this is with SubSonic 3?

Comment: This is with Subsonic 3, yes. Can you fix it or do I, what is the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely seems to be a bug in the ActiveRecord templates. You should submit an issue to the google code repository http://code.google.com/p/subsonicthree/issues/list. Check the bug isn't already listed first.